# go x/crypto/ssh client ssh version 1

Tags: go, ssh, cisco

I am needing to create an ssh client in my go app that will connect to a cisco switch and pull a configuration.  Ive done this on many other cisco switches with no issues.  The problem with this one is that it will only do ssh1 and not ssh2.

One of the restrictions is that the switch cannot be modified so I cannot do anything to the switch to get it to allow ssh2.

I have always used x/crypto/ssh for my client operations but I do not see any configuration option in there that will do ssh1 connections.  It just fails to handshake.

Is there a way to configure the ssh client in the x/crypto/ssh package to do ssh version 1 connections?

Comment: SSH protocol 1 is literally *ancient*. You might be better off grabbing an equally ancient version of OpenSSH and use `exec.Command` on that.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is, and it is a challenge working inside these constraints.  Im really trying not to resort to `exec.Command` out, because I really dont like doing that and having to spawn extra processes, but if all else fails, I know there is that option.

Comment: What's wrong with executing another process? That's how lots of lots of things work already, like the `go` command for example, which will execute `git` to fetch git repos, which in turn may even execute `ssh` as a transport. SSH1 was obsolete long before `go` even existed, so there's little chance of anyone making the effort to write a native library.

Comment: Just a personal preference.  Nothing wrong with it.  I just dont like spawning extra processes unless I have to.  Its just more wheels and gears and bobbles and trinkets that could break be harder to troubleshoot when you factor in shell environments and exterior applications that are not within your control.  Plus, when I started programming, there wasnt a whole lot to exec out to do. You pretty much had to build your own, so I guess its a little old school in me as well.

Comment: Plus, it creates dependencies that can break your application.  If you exec out to run "/bin/foobar" and then someone or something removes or changes "/bin/foobar" then your app is now broke by something someone else did.  So I prefer to have as few dependencies as I can.

Comment: Yes, but you have to weigh all that against the existence of theoretical library which is probably hardly tested and of questionable origin since the protocol is rarely still in use and insecure.

Comment: Hence my inquiry about whether the x/crypto/ssh package could do it, and not some third party package, which I have seen is out there and have no interest in.  If the x/crypto/ssh can do SSH1, and Im just missing how to setup it, then I will use that because I have come to trust the x/crypto/ssh and use it for all my ssh operations.  If not, then I find a workaround, but you dont know until you ask, and that is the reason why this question is here.